# Переопределение статического метода в дочернем классе (PHP)

Tags: php, веб-программирование, ооп

Есть класс

```
class a {
    protected static $say = null;

    public static function say(){
        var_dump(self::$say);
    }
}
```

И дочерний класс

```
class b extends a {
    protected static $say = "hello"
}
```

если вызвать метод b::say(); , всё равно выводится null, хоть свойство я переопределил, что нужно сделать, чтобы в методе использовалось переопределённое свойство?

Comment: использовать `static::$say` ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php